# Detecting vertical lines robustly in python

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, computer-vision, ocr, hough-transform

I have an image (uploaded) and I am interested in extracting each cell to pass on to my OCR engine. The horizontal lines are just fine and I can extract using houghpp function in cv2 in python. But for vertical lines, there are some very unclear lines that are completely removed when looking at the binary image. Is there anyone with experience in OCR and vision problems how I can do it for this image?
Also please let me know if you have suggestions, I guess the alternative way is to extract corners of cells. Harris corner detector didn't work that well
[image: Image used for extracting cells for OCR]

Comment: Hello, I'm by no mean an expert in computer vision, but looking at the picture like this, the first idea for me would be to increase the contrast. That way maybe the vertical lines that are quite faded would show up a bit more?

Comment: @user3314570 improving contrast only helps human vision. A computer does not need high contrast. It can differentiate single gray values.

Comment: Hough transform should not have issues with finding your lines. Please provide the input to Hough transform. Most likely your preprocessing is not good.

Comment: I have mainly problem with the lines between 10 /81 or 74 / 3. Still hough transform easily misses these lines

Comment: Monospaced font and nicely consistent spacing. If all the forms are the same, you don't really need to look for the lines, definitely not all of them. Just the left and right edge and you could fit a precomputed grid to it. Or even just a vertical projection and cut it up where the spaces between columns are wide.